# new to javascript. I am trying to pass the value of a radio button as the name of an object in a javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, forms, radio-button

I have a function called speak. It takes in an object filled with arrays of fragments of sentences and spits out a random phrase. I have two of these objects.  Each with unique sentence fragments. Via radio button I would like to be able to choose which object is sent through the function and then push a button to make that happen. When I hard wire the function with one of the buttons it works fine, but that is not what I am going for. I have tried several different suggested methods from this site and others with no luck. The closest I get is when I can get the name of the object into the speak function, but it is only recognized as a string. Here is my html...

```
    <html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<!--    <script type="text/javascript" src="wrestlingGame.js"></script> -->
    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="speak" value=ToolBelt.commentary onClick="ToolBelt.handleClick(this)">commentary a<br/>
        <input type="radio" name="speak" value=ToolBelt.commentary1 onClick="ToolBelt.handleClick(this)">commentary b<br/>
    </div> 
    <button onclick="ToolBelt.speak()">Commentary</button>
    <div id="commentator"></div>
    <div id="lif"></div>

</body>
```

this version is not wired to the 'Commentary' button. It is instead wired to the radio buttons themselves and it does not work correctly. I am posting this because it is my most recent attempt.
Here is my complete javascript including the two objects and the speak function...

```
    var ToolBelt = {

commentary:{
exclamations: ["Wow! ", "Oh no! ", "God almighty! ", "Good Gracious! "],
leadIn: ["That was a nasty ", "What a powerful ", "A horrifying ", "That was an illegal "], 
strikes: ["uppercut!", "chairshot!", "Lucy lick!", "monkey punch!", "jab", "Bug meow!", "dropkick!"],
},

commentary1:{
exclamations: ["Moo! ", "Quack! ", "Bark! ", "Growl! "],
leadIn: ["Chupa chup ", "Spaghetti ", "Bubbling ", "Necktie "], 
strikes: ["uppercut!", "chairshot!", "Lucy lick!", "monkey punch!", "jab", "Bug meow!", "dropkick!"],
},

handleClick:function(object){
    this.speak(object.value);
},

speak:function(i){


    var string='';

    for(key in i){
        var arr = i[key];
        var x = this.random(0,arr.length);

        string += arr[x] + " ";
    }

    document.getElementById("commentator").innerHTML = string;
},

random: function(max, min){
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min)+min);
}
```

};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems here.

First, you cannot assign a JavaScript object as the value of an input element. Input element values can be strings only. What we can do with the value is have it contain the key of the ToolBelt object that we want to target:

```
<input type="radio" name="speak" value="commentary" onClick="ToolBelt.handleClick(this)">commentary a
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="speak" value="commentary1" onClick="ToolBelt.handleClick(this)">commentary b
```

Next, you must understand what the `this` is in the onClick handlers on your input elements. In this context, `this` refers to the DOM element itself. So in the ToolBelt.handleClick method, we will want to get the value from the passed DOM element:

```
handleClick: function (el) {
    this.speak(this[el.value]);
}
```

This will work, but it will generate commentary whenever we check one of the radio buttons. However, the presence of the "Commentary" button suggests that we want to generate commentary only when this button is clicked. To achieve this, we will have to remove the call to `speak` in our `handleClick` method and instead cache the currently selected commentary key:

```
currentCommentaryKey: null,
handleClick: function (el) {
    this.currentCommentaryKey = el.value;
}
```

Then we will alter the `speak` method to make use of the cached key (I have added a check to make sure the current commentary key is valid):

```
speak: function () {
    if (!this.hasOwnProperty(this.currentCommentaryKey)) { return; }
    var i = this[this.currentCommentaryKey];
    /* rest of speak method implementation */
}
```